# what type for declare variable from LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I don't know what variable result from LINQ.
I want create variable empty for result LINQ. let's see example for detail

```
int Id = 1;
IEnumerable<object> permission = null;
if(Id != 0) {
    permission = from x in db.foo
                 join y in db.bar
                 on x.Id equal y.fkBar
                 select new {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Name = y.Name }
    permission = permission.where(a => a.Name = "xxxx")
} else {
    permission = from x in db.foo
                 select new {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Name = "" }
    permission = permission.where(a => a.Name = "yyyyy")
}
return permission;
```

Error in `where clause` 'object' does not contain a definition fo 'Name' and no accesible extention method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: Create a class unles you won´t use `object`.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [dynamic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) I don't know if it's a good idea to use it, though.

Comment: You have met anonymous types. Although they are useful, sometimes they are not. In your use case you would need to create a class and avoid using the anonymous type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class with `Id` and `Name` as properties, `permission` would then become an `IEnumerable<YourClassName>`.

```
int Id = 1;
IEnumerable<YourClassName> permission = null;
if(Id != 0) {
    permission = from x in db.foo
        join y in db.bar
        on x.Id equal y.fkBar
        select new YourClassName {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = y.Name }
} else {
    permission = from x in db.foo
        select new YourClassName {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = "" }
}

return permission;
```

IMO, classes are the way to go in this type of situation and much safer than just using `dynamic` or `object` types.

Comment: I dont create className. I'm using `IEnumerable<object>`. But not working..

Comment: *Error:* IEnumerable<object> is a type, which is not valid in the given content @Phil.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you an example, could you try something like that?

Comment: thank.. I say error before because i code `var permission = IEnumerable<object>`. so Stupid me. @Phil

Comment: In that case, you would be missing the `new` keyword, i.e. `var permission = new List<object>()`. Please mark my answer as the correct one if this helped.

Comment: error when I adding where below LINQ. `permission = permission.Where(a=> a.Name == "blah-blah"` It's canot read the `Name` @Phil

Comment: Still need your help. Error when adding `where clause` @Phil

Comment: That looks correct to me but of course I don't have access to your error output, can you show me the exact error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185604/discussion-between-phil-and-stfvns).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring using `var permission` use `dynamic permission = null` and it will work